# "I hope I enjoy myself very much" is this correct?

Tags: grammar, tenses, infinitives

> I hope I enjoy myself very much

I came across the above expression when I was reading something, the writer wasn't a native English speaker. She was talking about visiting a place she wanted to go, but I'm not sure if the sentence is grammatically correct.

I'm not sure what is wrong, but it doesn't feel right.

I would appreciate very much if you could tell me what kind of error this is, if it is, and how I can change the expression to make it right.

Comment: I would favour - _I very much hope I will enjoy myself._  Or better yet _I hope I will enjoy myself._

Comment: There's nothing specifically *wrong* with OP's sentence - it's just a slightly odd thing to say in the first place. Usually you'd just say *"I hope I [will] enjoy myself"*, because you're hoping for the first of two possibilities: either you'll enjoy yourself, or you *won't*. Semantically, it's more likely the optional *very much* qualification would be applied *to your act of hoping* (as per Philip's rephrasing). It seems rather strange to tack it on to the *end* of the statement (where it can only modify the hoped-for future enjoyment).

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong with it apart from a little ambiguity that may not matter much anyway. It might mean:

"I very much hope ... " putting the emphasis on the verb;

whereas "... enjoy myself very much" puts the emphasis on the enjoyment.